# how to be sure in Linq to SQL that record has been added successfully or not?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I am just learning Linq to SQL and don't know much. Kindly guide and help me.

I am adding a new record by using a SubmitChanges();  How I can be confirmed that record has been added? For example, in using stored procedures we use to send a flag back to application but how is it done in LINQ to SQL? Please guide me.

Comment: If the function returns, the record has been added. An exception gets thrown if the record cannot be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow your code to flow out of your method. Only when an exception is throw has your statement not completed.

If you wanted a 'flag', you *could* return a bool.

```
public bool AddCustomer()
{
  try{
     ....
     db.SubmitChanges();
     return true;
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    ...
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this;

```
public void Save()
{
    Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");
    // Make changes here. 
    try
    {
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        //Log error
    }
}
```

If no exception is thrown you can assume the data is saved correct. Though another option is something like this.

```
public bool Save()
{
    Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");
    // Make changes here. 
    try
    {
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Log the error
        return false;
    }
}
```

True will be returned if save succeeds, otherwise false will be returned

Answer (score 2):

See: [MSDN, How to: Submit Changes to the Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Note that there is an [overload of SubmitChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345081.aspx) that will let you specidy how to handle conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx

At this point, any errors detected by the database cause the submission process to stop, and an exception is raised. All changes to the database are rolled back as if no submissions ever occurred. The DataContext still has a full recording of all changes. You can therefore try to correct the problem and call SubmitChanges again

```
Northwnd db = new Northwnd(@"c:\northwnd.mdf");
// Make changes here. 
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (ChangeConflictException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    // Make some adjustments.
    // ...
    // Try again.
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```